# Solve for effect size using T Test inputs in C#

Tags: python, c#, statistics

I am trying to replicate a function in c# that I used in a Python project.

The library I used in Python was "statsmodels" and the function is `TTestPower.solve_power(` and it looks as follows:

```
TTestPower.solve_power(effect_size=None, nobs=None, alpha=None, power=None, alternative='two-sided')
```

```
nobs: number of observations (100)
alpha: significance level (0.05)
power: power of the test (0.8)
```

It solves for any one parameter (which remains none) of the power of a one-sample t-test using scipy.optimize.

As the title suggests I want to solve for the effect size with given nobs, alpha and power for the two-sided test.

Any suggestions on how to solve this in c#?

Thank you very much!

I tried to find solutions online but ended up mostly in the regular t-test.

I also asked chat-gpt but it turned out that the libraries it suggests do not exist (e.g in the Math.Numerics library the class TTestPower)

Comment: Is the source for `statsmodels` available?

Comment: The Code for the function can be found here: 

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/stats/power.py

Comment: Then use that to base your C# version on.